# Is there a .NET DataSet Constraint for bubbling id changes?

Tags: c#, datatable, foreign-keys

### What I want to do

I want to cross-reference index columns of .NET4.0 `DataTable`s. My use case is that I have a table with data using temporary primary keys. These keys are referenced in other tables. Here is an example:

```
     Reference Table with temporary ids
     ╔════╦════════════╗
     ║ id ║ Name       ║
     ╠════╬════════════╣
     ║ -1 ║ Blubb      ║
     ║ -3 ║ Bla        ║
     ║ -7 ║ Plisch     ║
     ╚════╩════════════╝
       ^
╔════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ id ║ ref_id ║ Name        ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ -1     ║ Refs Blubb  ║
║  2 ║ -3     ║ Refs Bla    ║
║  3 ║ -7     ║ Refs Plisch ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to be able to change the temporary ids of the reference table into real DB ids in this one table only and have the other ids change automagically. So after changing one id in the reference table it should look like this.

```
     Reference Table with one valid and two temporary ids
     ╔════╦════════════╗
     ║ id ║ Name       ║
     ╠════╬════════════╣
     ║ 42 ║ Blubb      ║ <- -1 changed to 42 (bubbles up to depending tables)
     ║ -3 ║ Bla        ║
     ║ -7 ║ Plisch     ║
     ╚════╩════════════╝
       ^
╔════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ id ║ ref_id ║ Name        ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ 42     ║ Refs Blubb  ║
║  2 ║ -3     ║ Refs Bla    ║
║  3 ║ -7     ║ Refs Plisch ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

I know how I would do this manually but maybe there is a way to fit this behavior into a dataset constraint, so I don't have to invent the wheel once more :-)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How aboput looking at [C# DataTable Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm aware of dataset constraints (see my last paragraph), I just thought this could be something that .NET already has implemented somewhere and I simply didn't find the needle in the haystack. If this is not the case using a custom constraint would be my fist bet :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this now, there seems to be no such thing that is built into the framework.